# Product status goes to online instead of pending review when seller lists a product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I am using dokan plugin and dokan theme for third party sellers to list their products on the main site. But the issue is when a seller adds a product using his dokan dashboard, product is going to published (online) directly. It should go to pending review instead of online. What functionality i have to change to get this work as before that is product status should be pending review instead of online when seller is adding a new product.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/ set seller role to just add product

Comment: some days ago it was working fine but something changed so it is going to online directly, i don't want to use plugin

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to wp-admin->Dokan->Settings->Selling Options->Then select "Pending Review" for the "New Product Status" option.

It will pending the seller products instead of publishing directly. However, if you want to allow to publish directly for individual seller then navigate to wp-admin->User->edit specific seller profile->then enable the 'Publishing' option.